# Delphi XE2 TChart PointSeries Bug

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

I have the following problem.

I was using Delphi 2010 and I recently installed Delphi XE2 and recompiled my different projects. I noticed a bug ? in the pointseries of tchart.

When I add points to a pointseries, the last point is not display or only when no other points are shown ???

At first draw everything is fine :

[image]

Then I clear the serie and re-add the same points
The last point is not displayed

[image]

however if I slide the graph so that no other point appears on screen, this missing point shows up

[image]

Any idea or help ?

Comment: Could you please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here? You can send your files at www.steema.net/upload/. Also, are you using the TeeChart version shipped in Delphi XE2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me a few minutes to prepare the example of the problem. I am a Steema Customer but only up to version 2010. For now my boss don't want to buy updated because standard Tchart shipped with Delphi is sufficient for our needs. So yes I use standard tchart.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet I have uploaded the file "PointSeriesBug_HpTerm_SO". There is a readme file that recalls the problem. Shortly : the point at x=255 is missing on my screen. If i right click and slide until all other points disappear from screen, the missing point appears.

Comment: thanks for the files. See my reply below

Comment: Don't know, it was not me. You may find some ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not reproduce the issue here using build 2012.07.121105, that's what I get:

[image]

Do you have Update 4 + hotfix 1 installed in XE2? You can download a TeeChart upgrade for update 4 at Embarcadero downloads: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28780

Comment: OK it solved the problem, but now it asks to recompile dclFMXtee9160.bpl I searched the web but didn't find any information how to recompile that ?

Comment: This error message probably indicates that your Delphi is referencing different versions of the TeeChart packages. You should check that its search library paths don't have old versions references.

Comment: Ok thanks. As it's another point I validate your answer. Thank you very much for your quick answer.

Comment: I had the same problem.  The update solved it.  Thanks!